# Testing system in beamer

Tags: beamer, forms, javascript

Can I use `\radioButton` option in Beamer? I need to make test(choice) system with counting right answers in presentation mode, maybe there's any class for making testing. I have error with `\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}`. Can anybody help please?:)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: [Exerquiz][1] seems to be the package you are looking for.  
It is part of the AcroTeX Bundle as well.  
[Here are examples][2] of what you can do with it.  
What is the error you get?


  [1]: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exerquiz
  [2]: http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/webeq.html

Comment: As it stands, this will not get answered. We've no real idea of what the error(s) are or indeed a more detailed description of the document you are using: a MWE is usually a very good idea.